# My navigation drop down menu won't stay open on hover

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

I am having an issue with my navigation drop down menu. It is not staying open when I hover down the list. As soon as I hover off of the initial link, it goes away. I have tried and tried and can't seem to find the problem. The sub menu opens sometimes but on other browsers it doesn't stay open ever. Please help.

CSS Mark up

```
nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:99;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    height:auto;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width:800px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    transition: max-height 0.3s linear;
    color:#171A58;
    padding:2px;
    height:auto;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;

}

nav ul li ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    color:#171A58;
    padding:7px;
    text-align:left;

}

nav ul li ul li a:visited {
    color:#171A58;

}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    color:#F02204;

}
nav ul li ul li a:active {
    color:#171A58;

}
```

HTML

```
    <nav>
<!--Top Navigation Links (top horizontal navigation bar)-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.html">About</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="metro-chiefs.html">Metro Chiefs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ccfd.html">Clark County Fire Department</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.regonline.com/Register/Checkin.aspx?EventID=1558172" class="nav1">Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="conference.html">Conference</a></li>

            <li><a href="sponsors.html" class="nav1">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Please help me with this. It has been kicking my butt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be the ten pixel margin added in the hover state (though I'm not sure why.)

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:10px; <-- removing this should fix it
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/casijiru/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thank you! That worked but now the drop down box does not line up with the container. Any fix for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Here's an example of a pure CSS drop-down menu system: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/nrAPu/

Comment: "  it doesn't stay open "

Answer (score 1):

it's a normal issue  because your drop down menu is in **relation** with hover and if you mouse out then the **Hover** detective you will not be able create a drop down with :hover ,
there another simple and elegant way to do that and also you controller every aspect .

you should use SlideToglle in JQuery you will find a help full documentation . in JQuery website .

---

Solution with JavaScript add this CSS style to you CSS

```
.show-sub {
    display: block;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;
}
```

and Delete this from your css

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;

}
```

and modifie your HTML to

```
    <li><a id ="item" onmouseover="showmenu(this)" href="#.html">About</a>
        <ul id="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="metro-chiefs.html">Metro Chiefs</a></li>
            <li><a href="ccfd.html">Clark County Fire Department</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

add this script to your html ,

```
 < script >
    var item = document.getElementById('item');
    function showmenu() {
    var submenu = document.getElementById('sub-menu');  
    submenu.className = "show-sub";
    }

</ script>
```

It's work with me

Comment: Does the Hover selector make it not remain open? I'm looking for a solution to keep it open when I hover down over the sub list.

Comment: I modified my answer @TheKirkConcept .

Answer (score 1):

The :hover selector is used to select elements when you mouse over them.

Comment: Is there a reason why it won't stay open? Is the :hover selector making it close?

Comment: Exactly, :hover selector making it close. With :hover you can' make what you want to do. Try to use jQuery and mouseover. In this place you have a example: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/